# WPF Datagrid ValidationRules on ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid

I want to put a red-border around a DataGrid when it has no rows (Im doing the binding to ItemsSource).

So i was following this guide for WPF Validation:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation

Anyhow, it is simple enough to make a textbox have such an error when the `Text = ""`:

[image: empty textbox error]

and even customize the error:

[image: green]

I tried debugging and the ValidationRules that are bound within my ItemsSource are never invoked.

```
<DataGrid ...>
 <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
   <Binding Path="Lines" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
       <Binding.ValidationRules>
         <DataGridValidationRule
               MiniumRows="1"
               MaximumRows="100"
               ErrorMessage="must have between 1 and 100 rows">
         </DataGridValidationRule>
       </Binding.ValidationRules>
     </Binding>
 </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
</DataGrid>
```

And then the DataGridValidtionRule class looks like this:

```
public class  public class StringRangeValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    private int _minimumRows = -1;
    private int _maximumRows = -1;
    private string _errorMessage;

    public int MinimumRows
    {
        get { return _minimumRows ; }
        set { _minimumRows  = value; }
    }

    public int MaximumRows
    {
        get { return _maximumLength; }
        set { _maximumLength = value; }
    }

    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get { return _errorMessage; }
        set { _errorMessage = value; }
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, 
        CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult(true, null);
        ObservableCollection<Lines> lines = (ObservableCollection<Lines>) value;
        if (lines.Count < this.MinimumRows||
               (this.MaximumRows> 0 &&
                lines.Count > this.MaximumRows))
        {
            result = new ValidationResult(false, this.ErrorMessage);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And the "Lines" class

```
 public class Line
  {
    public Line(string f, string b)
    {
      foo = f;
      bar = b;
    }
   public string Foo {get; set;}
   public string Bar {get; set;}
  }
```

EDIT:

It turns out that my "delete row" button for my datagrid was removing from the `ObservableCollection` but not through the actual DataGrid (it was removing at the ViewModel)... and for some reason this prevents the Validation call from being invoked.

So again the View:

```
<DataGrid Name="mygrid">
 <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
   <Binding Path="Lines" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
       <Binding.ValidationRules>
         <DataGridValidationRule
               MiniumRows="1"
               MaximumRows="100"
               ErrorMessage="must have between 1 and 100 rows">
         </DataGridValidationRule>
       </Binding.ValidationRules>
     </Binding>
 </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
</DataGrid>
```

so if i had in the ViewModel:

```
void delete(Line l)
{
  Lines.Remove(l); //if you delete everything (grid empty) there won't be any error shown.
}
```

The error border & icon wouldn't show up around the datagrid.

But if instead i put a event that directly changed the ItemsSource like this:

```
 void delete(Line l)
    {
      Lines.Remove(l);
      myView.mygrid.ItemsSource = Lines; // this magically fixes everything... even though it was already bound to Lines... though i hate to directly access the View from within the ViewModel.
    }
```

I'm not sure why exactly... but that fixed it.
Any ideas on how i could separate the view from the VM?  I don't really like this fix.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the datagrid in a border and attach a trigger to it to make it red once datagrid is empty

```
<Border Margin="20" >
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding ISEmpty}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <DataGrid  Name="myGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lecturers}" >

    </DataGrid>
</Border>
```

Set IsEmpty property to true when you clear the grid

```
private bool iSEmpty;

public bool ISEmpty
{
    get { return iSEmpty; }
    set
    {
        iSEmpty = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ISEmpty");
    }
}
```

Clear your item source collection

```
viewmodel.Lecturers.Clear();
this.viewmodel.ISEmpty = true;
```

Future work. You can bind trigger to datagrid control.

Comment: I thought about doing something like that...
But do you know why the Datagrid as a whole doesn't seem to work with the Validation class?